# "bundle failed: 'InMemoryBackendService' is not exported " when update Ionic2 RC0 from BETA11

Tags: angular, npm, upgrade, ionic2

error:[bundle failed: 'InMemoryBackendService' is not exported by node_modules\angular2-in-memory-web-api\index.js
            (imported by src\app\app.module.ts). For help fixing this error see https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module]

before
app.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';
import {InMemoryBackendService} from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SplashPage} from './pages/splash/splash';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: []
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any = SplashPage;

  constructor(
  ) {}
}

ionicBootstrap(
  MyApp,
  [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService}
  ]
);
```

after
app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import {InMemoryBackendService} from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import {XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {ServerConfig} from '../server-config';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService}
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to create a new file in the app folder called *in-memory-backend.service.ts* with the following content:

````
//import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
//import { Headers, Request, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
///**
//* Seed data for in-memory database`enter code here`
//* Must implement InMemoryDbService.
//*/
//export declare const SEED_DATA: OpaqueToken;
///**
//* Interface for a class that creates an in-memory database
//* Safe for consuming service to morph arrays and objects.
//*/
//export interface InMemoryDbService {
//    /**
//    * Creates "database" object hash whose keys are collection names
//    * and whose values are arrays of the collection objects.
//    *
//    * It must be safe to call again and should return new arrays with new objects.
//    * This condition allows InMemoryBackendService to morph the arrays and objects
//    * without touching the original source data.
//    */
//    createDb(): {};
//}
///**
//* Interface for InMemoryBackend configuration options
//*/
//export interface InMemoryBackendConfigArgs {
//    /**
//     * default response options
//     */
//    defaultResponseOptions?: ResponseOptions;
//    /**
//     * delay (in ms) to simulate latency
//     */
//    delay?: number;
//    /**
//     * false (default) if ok when object-to-delete not found; else 404
//     */
//    delete404?: boolean;
//    /**
//     * host for this service
//     */
//    host?: string;
//    /**
//     * root path before any API call
//     */
//    rootPath?: string;
//}
///**
//*  InMemoryBackendService configuration options
//*  Usage:
//*    provide(InMemoryBackendConfig, {useValue: {delay:600}}),
//*/
//export declare class InMemoryBackendConfig implements InMemoryBackendConfigArgs {
//    constructor(config?: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs);
//}
///**
//* Interface for object w/ info about the current request url
//* extracted from an Http Request
//*/
//export interface ReqInfo {
//    req: Request;
//    base: string;
//    collection: any[];
//    collectionName: string;
//    headers: Headers;
//    id: any;
//    resourceUrl: string;
//}
//export declare const isSuccess: (status: number) => boolean;
///**
// * Simulate the behavior of a RESTy web api
// * backed by the simple in-memory data store provided by the injected InMemoryDataService service.
// * Conforms mostly to behavior described here:
// * http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html
// *
// * ### Usage
// *
// * Create InMemoryDataService class the implements IInMemoryDataService.
// * Register both this service and the seed data as in:
// * ```
// * // other imports
// * import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend } from 'angular2/http';
// * import { InMemoryBackendConfig, InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from '../in-memory-backend/in-memory-backend.service';
// * import { InMemoryStoryService } from '../api/in-memory-story.service';
// *
// * @Component({
// *   selector: ...,
// *   templateUrl: ...,
// *   providers: [
// *     HTTP_PROVIDERS,
// *     provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: InMemoryBackendService }),
// *     provide(SEED_DATA, { useClass: InMemoryStoryService }),
// *     provide(InMemoryBackendConfig, { useValue: { delay: 600 } }),
// *   ]
// * })
// * export class AppComponent { ... }
// * ```
// */
//export declare class InMemoryBackendService {
//    private _seedData;
//    protected _config: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs;
//    protected _db: {};
//    constructor(_seedData: InMemoryDbService, config: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs);
//    createConnection(req: Request): {
//        response: Observable<{}>;
//    };
//    /**
//     * Process Request and return an Http Response object
//     * in the manner of a RESTy web api.
//     *
//     * Expect URI pattern in the form :base/:collectionName/:id?
//     * Examples:
//     *   api/characters
//     *   api/characters/42
//     *   api/characters.json/42   // ignores the ".json"
//     *   commands/resetDb  // resets the "database"
//     */
//    protected _handleRequest(req: Request): Response;
//    protected _clone(data: any): any;
//    /**
//     * When the `base`="commands", the `collectionName` is the command
//     * Example URLs:
//     *   commands/resetdb   // Reset the "database" to its original state
//     *   commands/config (GET) // Return this service's config object
//     *   commands/config (!GET) // Update the config (e.g. delay)
//     *
//     * Usage:
//     *   http.post('commands/resetdb', null);
//     *   http.get('commands/config');
//     *   http.post('commands/config', '{"delay":1000}');
//     */
//    protected _commands(reqInfo: ReqInfo): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _createErrorResponse(status: number, message: string): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _delete({ id, collection, collectionName, headers }: ReqInfo): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _findById(collection: any[], id: number): any;
//    protected _genId(collection: any): any;
//    protected _get({ id, collection, collectionName, headers }: ReqInfo): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _getLocation(href: string): HTMLAnchorElement;
//    protected _indexOf(collection: any[], id: number): number;
//    protected _parseId(id: string): any;
//    protected _parseUrl(url: string): {
//        base: string;
//        id: string;
//        collectionName: string;
//        resourceUrl: string;
//    };
//    protected _post({ collection, headers, id, req, resourceUrl }: ReqInfo): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _put({ id, collection, collectionName, headers, req }: ReqInfo): ResponseOptions;
//    protected _removeById(collection: any[], id: number): boolean;
//    /**
//     * Reset the "database" to its original state
//     */
//    protected _resetDb(): void;
//    protected _setStatusText(options: ResponseOptions): ResponseOptions;
//}
````

and then add the proper path to this newly created file in main.ts.